# Hibernate Jpa custom query

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, jackson

I'm facing a problem that makes me sweat.

first pojo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "generic_params")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type", defaultImpl = Void.class)
public class GenericParams extends AbstractParam {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "code", unique = true)
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "type", insertable = false, updatable = false, unique = true)
    private String type;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "genericParams", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<LabelTranslation> labelTranslations = new HashSet<>();
    ...getter / setter
```

second pojo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "label_translation")
public class LabelTranslation extends AbstractParam {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "label")
    private String label;

    @ManyToOne
    private Language language;

    @Column(name = "language_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long languageId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference
    private GenericParams genericParams;

    @Column(name = "generic_params_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long genericParamsId;
```

GenericParamsMapper

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = { LabelTranslationMapper.class })
public interface GenericParamsMapper extends GenericParamsParameterizedMapper<GenericParams> {

    @Override
    GenericParamsDTO toDto(GenericParams genericParams);

    @Override
    GenericParams toEntity(GenericParamsDTO genericParamsDTO);

    @Override
    GenericParams fromSuperClassToDerived(GenericParams genericParams);
}
```

The problem when I make the request to return a type of GenericParams it returns all LabelTranslation without filter.
My request:

```
@Query(value = " SELECT gparam FROM  GenericParams gparam  " //
    + " INNER JOIN gparam.labelTranslations label with label.languageId =:lang " //
    + " WHERE gparam.type =:type " //
    + " AND   gparam.deleted = false ") //
    List<GenericParams> getGenericParamByFilteringLabelTranslation(@Param("lang") Long lg, @Param("type") String tp);
```

this request is called by :

```
@Override
public List<GenericParamsDTO> getGenericParamsByType(String type, HttpServletRequest request) {
    Long idLang = this.languageService.findIdByCulture(request.getLocale().toLanguageTag());
    List<GenericParams> gList = this.genericParamsRepository.getGenericParamByFilteringLabelTranslation(idLang, type);
    result this.genericParamsMapper.toDto(gList);
}
```

Here it is supposed to retrieve a list of GenericParams with the filter on LabelTranslation which have the 2L language for example
except that here it returns all LabelTranslation  without filter.
You'll say yes because the mapper ignores the property.
I will tell you that I need to ignore it for other need.
So how do i ignore it for one need and filter it for another.
Getter and setter are omitted in order to simplify
thanks for lending me a hand.

it was more challenging than I thought
by analyzing the queries executed by hibernate, I realized the error.
despite that i don't know how to solve it.

This first request is good:

```
  select gp.* from generic_params gp 
    inner join label_translation labeltrans1_ 
    on gp.id=labeltrans1_.generic_params_id and (labeltrans1_.language_id=? and labeltrans1_.language_id=?) 
    where gp.type=? 
    and gp.is_deleted=0;
```

but this returns the false information (since it is executed automatically by Hibernate)
so it's a design problem

```
select * from label_translation lb 
left outer join lang lang on lb.language_id=lang.id 
where lb.generic_params_id=?
```

now how do i tell hibernate to execute a request like this?

```
select label.* from label_translation label 
left outer join lang langue on label.language_id=langue.id 
where label.generic_params_id=200
and langue.id=2;
```

you will notice that I just added this piece of code:

```
and langue.id=2;
```

So to make a summary, I left things as they are and I added in the mapper a method that filters on LabelTransaltion and I have the right result.
a second option is to make two requests:
- The first one returns the GenericParams
- The second one returns the LabelTransaltion and then in the GenericParams object i set the list of LabelTransaltion by the 2nd request.
**But I wonder if there is another more concise hibernate way.**
thank you

Comment: finally I added a method in the GenericParamsMapper to do the filter I was looking for.  
it's not what i want but at least i'm not blocked.  
If you have a solution, I'm interested

Comment: Hello @Filip,  
I did not know how stackOverflow works, I just saw your comment.  
Thank you for this remark.  
It is a purely jpa / hibernate problem but I finally reworked my mapper.  
It's not what I wanted but at least I don't get stuck on this problem.